# Increasing UINavigationController navigation bar height in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have seen too many posts on this but unable to find satisfactory answer to this question. Specifically, I want to increase the height of navigation bar of UINavigationController by around 20 pts when iPhone is in landscape mode (not otherwise), and also set a custom image for it's Background. What I have found so far:

1. Manipulating frame of UINavigationBar managed by navigation controller,
2. Hacks such as sizeThatFits along with subclassing UINavigationController -- doesn't work for me in iOS 12 and also it is a kind of hack,
3. Hide the default navigation bar in UINavigationController and instead replace it with a custom navigation bar. But I don't see any sample code. Any sample code will be appreciated.

Edit: Here is how I want my custom navigation bar to look like that works across UINavigation hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: Try this in landscape mode `self.navigationItem.prompt = "  "` and in portrait mode    `self.navigationItem.prompt = nil`

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't the titleView and right/left items also get pushed down with prompt?

Comment: How to recenter the title and bar items after the prompt?

Comment: Yup there is space above title and even if you try assign a frame to navbar still it works but spacing issue you have to face. For this solution you can adobt solution 2 that mentioned in your post.

Comment: Can you guide me how to replace the navigation bar in UINavigation controller that works in all view controllers in navigation stack? Or each view controller in the stack will have to adopt it's own navigation bar?

Comment: Please explain your final requirement? Above nav bar is required in one controller or in whole app ??

Comment: Ideally, whole app. I will post the screenshot shortly.

Comment: Ok I posted the screenshot of navigation bar in landscape mode.

Comment: I think its same regular bar height. Arn't it? After all I can explain multiple types to create navbar with effects but final call will be yours.

Comment: In landscape mode it is more than regular height.

Comment: Check the answer. If this does not work then let me know